# OpenLDAP gidnumber and uidnumber

Tags: linux, openldap

I'm trying to setup OpenLDAP server and client on linux (Centos).  After searching around a bit, my understanding is gidnumber and uidnumber work like uid and gid on unix, to identify a unique user and group.  My question is

- is there relationship between these LDAP and linux IDs? should the LDAP ones be the same as a user's uid/gid on linux (if I have such user already on the server host)?
- If not, after a client authenticate a user, the user creates a file on the client host, what would the user/group linux ownership of the file looks like?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Yes, and therefore
2. Not applicable.

Comment: thanks.  I wonder why many of the guide/doc don't just say that??  e.g. have been looking at this [one](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin24/OpenLDAP-Admin-Guide.pdf)

Comment: Because that's an administrator's guide, not a schema description.